# Showing that $k(x)$ is an algebraic extension of $k(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. Let $a\in k(x)-k$. Then, it is to be shown that $k(x)$ is an algebraic extension of $k(a)$.

It is clear that $k(a)\subset k(x)$. (because  $a\in k(x)-k$)

Since $k(a)$ is quotient field of $k[a]$, elements of $k(a)$ look like $f(a)/g(a)$, where $f,g\in k[x]$ and $g(a)\ne 0$.  Take any $f/g\in k(x)-k(a)$.  It is now to be shown that there exists a non zero polynomial in $k(a)[x]$  which has a root $f/g$.

**Claim**: $k(x)\cong k(a)$.

**Proof**: Here, $a$ is transcendental over $k$. If not, then $k(a)=k[a]$. Suppose that $a=p/q, (p,q)=1, q\ne0, p,q\in k(x)$. $$q/p\in k(a)\implies \exists b_i, q/p=b_0+b_1(p/q)+...+b_n(p/q)^n\implies q^{n+1}=(b_0q^n+...+b_np^n)p$$

It follows that $p|q\implies p,q$ are units. $\implies p/q=a\in k$, contradiction. Hence, $a$ is transcendental over $k$.

The following proves the claim.

Define $\phi:k(x)\to k(a)$ by $\phi(f(x)/g(x))=f(a)/g(a) $. (Note that $g(a)\ne 0$ as $a$ is algebraic over $k$).

It's clear that $\phi$ is onto homomorphism. In fact, $\phi$ is $1-1$ too as the following shows: $f(a)/g(a)=0\implies f(a)=0\implies f=0\implies \ker \theta=(0).$ So by the first isomorphism theorem, $k(x)\cong k(a). \square$

But since $k(a)\subset k(x)$, we must have $k(x)=k(a)\implies [k(x):k(a)]=1\implies k(x)$ is a finite extension of $k(a).\implies k(x)$ is an algebraic extension of $k(a)$.

Is this correct?  Thanks.

Comment: This doubt arises because the exercise has a part asking to prove that $[k(x):k(a)] =\max$ (deg p, deg q). But I don't understand how that is possible in view of the post above. Either the exercise is not correct or there must be something wrong above. Thanks.

Comment: You showed that $k(a)\simeq k(x)$. It does not follow that $k(a)=k(x)$. May be this is the first time you have run into the phenomenon of a field being isomorphic to its *proper* subfield? Like $k(x^2)\simeq k(x)$, but $[k(x):k(x^2)]=2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I understand, thanks a lot. I had finite dimensional vector spaces in mind while making that conclusion. vector space isomorphism ($U\cong V$)+ subspace $(U\subset V)\implies U=V$, if V is finite dimensional vector space. But that may not be the case here.

Comment: Correct, both $k(a)$ and $k(x)$ are infinite dimensional vector spaces over $k$. If $a=p(x)/q(x)$ then consider the polynomial $f(T):=p(T)-a q(T)$. Why is $f(T)$  a polynomial in $k(a)[T]$? Why is $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: $p(T), q(T)\in k[T]\subset k(a)[T], a\in k(a)[T]$ and $f(x)=0$ because of definition of $a$. This shows that $x$ is algebraic over $k(a)$.

Comment: Correct again. This is close to being a FAQ, but the first related thread I found is about [a specifi $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4633893/11619).

Comment: This is a standard result which is a precursor to Luroth theorem which says that any subfield (apart from $k$) of $k(x) $ must necessarily be of the form $k(a) $ for some $a\in k(x) \setminus k$ and hence isomorphic to $k(x) $. A similar result does not hold when two or more indeterminates are involved.